# Jquery (Mobile) and phonegap storage module not synchronized

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, cordova

I', new to the phonegap api and have som problems with the storage part together with loops. The loop will finish before fist call to executeSql.

Psudo Example:

list = [1,2,3]; 
// For this example id 1 has 3 tags, id 2 has 6 tags and id 3 has 9 tags.

$.each(list, function(index,value){
    alert(value);
    tx.executeSql('SELECT tag_name FROM Tag WHERE parent = '+value,[], function(tx, results){
         alert(results.rows.length);
    }, sqlError);
});

Desired result: 1,3,2,6,3,9
Result: 1,2,3,9,9,9

So the javascript is finished before tx is executed and the query will always be "SELECT tag_name FROM Tag WHERE parent = 3

Answer (score 1):

executeSql is an asynchronous method, so it will return after your javascript has finished: that's why you'll always get "1,2,3" first.

As for why you get "9,9,9" instead of "3,6,9" perhaps phonegap's implementation is using a static object for 'results' and it gets overwritten with latest call.

I advise you to execute a separate transaction per SELECT. Check the [documentation for transactions](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#SQLTransaction).

To achieve your desired result I would do the following:

```
$.each(list, function(index,value){ 
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
                tx.executeSql('SELECT tag_name FROM Tag WHERE parent = ' + value,
                        [],
                        function(tx, results) { 
                                alert(value);
                                alert(results.rows.length);
                        },
                        sqlError
                );
        });
});
```